# sql combining two distinct row entries as the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two distinct sport types in my database which mean the same thing

dash racing 1 ,
dash racing 2

I need to do a customer count specifically for Dash Racing and I would like sql to combine the customer count for dash racing 1 & 2 instead of me having to manually add them after.

Is there a way of doing this?

code looks as follows :

```
select  Sport ,
        count(distinct customerID ) 'CustCount' ,
        sum(Stake) 'TotalStake' ,
        sum(Return) 'TotalReturn'
from    table1
where   sport in ('dash horse racing' , 'dash horse racing 2')
group by Sport
```

which returns a table similar to this :

```
Sport   -----------------------   CustCount-------- TotalStake  --------    TotalReturn
dash Horse Racing 2
dash Horse Racing 1
```

however i want to combine VS racing 1 & 2, creating a new combined sport 'VS 
horse racing', getting a table like :

```
*Sport ----------- CustCount---------TotalStake----------TotalReturn*

*dash Horse Racing*
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The sample data and the the desired data are confusing, where is the cust count values in the sample data? Based on your sample data `select distinct sport from table` will solve your issues.

Comment: I am using microsoft 2014 server.

Comment: 'select distinct sport from table' does not combine the necessary row entries I want, i am counting customers by their CustomerID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just select the text you want and leave off the group by

```
select  'dash horse racing' as Sport ,
        count(distinct customerID ) 'CustCount' ,
        sum(Stake) 'TotalStake' ,
        sum(Return) 'TotalReturn'
from    table1
where   sport in ('dash horse racing' , 'dash horse racing 2')
```

Comment: I found another slightly different way using case when, but your way seems simpler when only wanting to combine two entries with no other results.